# Controlling the animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a whack-a-mole style game where a sum is given and numbers animate from the bottom of the container to the top. The aim of the game is to click the correct answer to the sum and collect as many correct answers as possible.

I have also added a couple of extra icons to make the game more fun. One of the icons is a flame which speeds up the animation for 5 seconds.

At the moment it makes all the icons move really fast all at once. Instead of this happening I want the flow to continue as usual, but at a faster pace.

This is what I have so far..

```
$(".character").click(clickThrottled(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("heat")) {
        $(this).effect("explode", 400);
        $("#container").children().css('top', '400px').fadeIn(1000).animate({
            'top': '-100px'
        }, 3000).fadeOut(1000);
    }
}));
```

Can someone show me where I am going wrong? Look at the demo and click the flame icon to get a better understanding of the problem.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pUwKb/52/

Answer (score 2):

Easing will make all the elements ease to the top at the same time, but in a stylish way (like they slow down at the end.)

What you actually need to do is keep a flag called 'isFlameOn' or 'speedModifier' would be better. When a flame icon is clicked, set 'speedModifier' to equal like 2 or 3, which will make the speed twice or three times as fast as normal.

Remove this:

```
$("#container").children().css('top', '400px').fadeIn(1000).animate({
        'top': '-100px'
}, 3000).fadeOut(1000);
```

Because you will be changing the speed of objects individually.

Now go down to wherever you manage each icon (move them) and instead of saying: item[i].y -= item[i].speed;

Do item[i].y -= item[i].speed * speedModifier;

If you make them animate to get to the top, then you will need to keep track of each of those animate intervals and reset them. So if you create an item and then .animate it, you will need to remove that .animate effect and create a new one with the compensated speedModifier percent. You will have an easy day if you did it frame by frame instead :).

When you want the flame effect to run out, just set speedModifier back to 1. If you animated each item, you'll need to again remove the current .animate and replace it with a normal speed. Be sure to keep track of each item's random speed so that you can reset its speed back to the original speed after the effect wears off.

Comment: Do you have an example? @Banath

Answer (score 1):

Look at the different [easings](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/) provided by jQuery UI, they should solve your problem. To use them just set property easing of `animate` (if you need more advanced ones you should also include jQuery UI).

For further customization you can use the `step` callback of `animate`.